# Dotnet framework error when using Visual Studio Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So i am trying to make my first aplication using C# and Visual studio but every time i try to make one I get the following error:
`Could not find a part of path 'C:\Users\Myusername\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v6.0.201\packages'`
Here is a sceenshot of what my screen is:
[image]

I tried installing the .net framework i tried mostly everything i could find as tips. Could you share a download link for the .NET framework or if you could explain to me why it doesn't work. I would be greatly appreciative

EDIT:
For anyone out there, creating the folder should fix  the issue for a bit but a more sustainable way to fix this is to uninstall and reinstall visual studio again. If that doesn't work, try updating your Visual studio or worst case scenario, ask on visual studios forums for help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's related to your issue, but i would avoid using spaces in project name, it can cause some trouble.

Comment: I tried without it and it gave me the same error. Maybe its something to do with me not having the right framework or version. I am not quite sure how to even start with a C# app and this is my first time. I tried downloading .NET .net framework .net client and none of those worked for some reason. If you could could you provide a link to a download or another post covering this topic. I would be greatful

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there having the same issue to resolve it you can just do the following:
1- Goto CMD (by typing cmd in the search bar) and type:
`cd .templateengine\v<the version your error throws at you>`
And then do `dir` to check all of the items within the folder. If you don't see a directory named `packages` then go ahead and do: `mkdir packages` which will create a directory named packages. Now boot up Visual studio and create your project. Now you should not get any errors and Visual studio should boot up your project.